# Getting json object not display in order

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

every body
I have a problem,
I send a json with angular, that is my code in angular:

```js
function ctlApp($scope){
 $scope.weekday={

  "sat" : {
   "code" : "1",
   "Persian" : "شنبه"
  },

  "sun" : {
   "code" : "2",
   "Persian" : "یکشنبه"
  },

  "mon" : {
   "code" : "3",
   "Persian" : "دوشنبه"
  },

  "tus" : {
   "code" : "4",
   "Persian" : "سه شنبه"
  },

  "wed" : {
   "code" : "5",
   "Persian" : "چهارشنبه"
  },

  "thr" : {
   "code" : "6",
   "Persian" : "پنجشنبه"
  },

  "fri" : {
   "code" : "7",
   "Persian" : "جمعه"
  }
 };
}
```

then I Get it in the index.html: like this

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/app.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <h1></h1>

<div class="container" ng-controller="ctlApp">
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid" >
  <div class="span1" id="weekday" ng-repeat="day in weekday">
        {{day.Persian}}
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>

{{ weekday | json}}  
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

but not shown me in order and that seems randomly shows all,
as you see in above code ' {{ weekday | json}} ' it hasn't problem,

what i did wrong?

thanks in advance...